# Configure health rule in AppDynamics for multiple servers reboot or down

Tags: appdynamics

How to configure health rule in AppDynamics to alert when ever multiple servers reboot or when multiple servers are down?

Comment: Hi - do you mean you would like an alert that triggers when each server goes down or one which flags when multiple servers have gone down at the same time? Are you just using APM agents or are you also using Machine Agents / Server Visibility or Cluster Agents?

Comment: i would like alert that triggers when multiple servers are down. I am using Machine Agents.

Comment: Are the servers in a single Tier?

Comment: Yes, Servers are in single Tier.

Answer (score 0):

How to create a Health Rule using Machine Agent metrics to report when multiple servers are down (at the same time) where the servers are Nodes within the same Tier:

- Click 'Alert & Respond' (at top of UI)
- Select the relevant Application from the drop down menu
- Click 'Health Rules'
- Click '+'
- In 'Overview' Tab

  - Enter a 'Name' value / set time window options
- In 'Affected Entities' Tab

  - Click 'Tier / Node Health - Hardware, JVM, disk I/O, etc)'
  - Ensure 'Tiers' is selected in the Radio underneath
  - Select "These specific Tiers" in drop-down
  - Select the relevant Tier and move to 'Selected' (to the left)
- In the 'Critical Criteria' Tab

  - Click "+ Add Condition"
  - Click "Select a Metric"
  - Navigate to and select "Agent|Machine|Availability"
  - Change the conditions to be is "< Specific Value" with value "1"
  - Then under "Health Rule will violate if the conditions above evaluate to true for:" click the third option and enter value "100" so this reads "100% of the Nodes"
- Save

The above can be tweaked to your needs in terms of evaluation window / violation wait etc, you will need a Policy and an Action for the the Health Rule to send email or do any other kind of work based on the event created when the Health Rule violates.

Related Official Docs:

- https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.5/en/appdynamics-essentials/alert-and-respond/health-rules
- https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.5/en/appdynamics-essentials/alert-and-respond/configure-health-rules
- https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.5/en/appdynamics-essentials/alert-and-respond/actions
- https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.5/en/appdynamics-essentials/alert-and-respond/policies